# How can I make linear progress indicator to animate like that?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have linear progress indicator.I want it animate as it shown in gif file that I provided.I can not find a way for doing the same approach.
[image: it is gif you can see here]

[image: I want to get this one]

I tried to use Shimmer,but animation transitions is not same.How can I make this animation?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: you can wrap your widget with `opacity` animation  : https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/animation/opacity-animation

Comment: Check this https://medium.com/@dtejaswini.06/progressive-shade-animation-in-flutter-17dcb5e380ff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i mention i the comment, you can use `Opacity`

```
class BlinkingWidget extends AnimatedWidget {
  const BlinkingWidget({
    super.key,
    required AnimationController controller,
    this.child,
  }) : super(listenable: controller);
  final Widget? child;

  Animation<double> get _opacity => listenable as Animation<double>;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedOpacity(
      // If the widget is visible, animate to 0.0 (invisible).
      // If the widget is hidden, animate to 1.0 (fully visible).
      opacity: _opacity.value > 0.5 ? 1.0 : 0.0,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      // The green box must be a child of the AnimatedOpacity widget.
      child: child ??
          Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

and use it like below:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: BlinkingWidget(
        controller: _controller,
        child: LinearProgressIndicator( 
          value: 200 / 785, 
          minHeight: 30,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

you can use any widget as `child`.

full code here : https://dartpad.dev/?id=bb2ccf9b9dd3399fb124142018299dc9

result:

[image]

Comment: Sir after applying your approach I get such an error.                                               Still can not find how to solve it.Error-Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.

To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.